# See other Windows computer in Network but cannot connect to it?

Tags: windows, networking

When I open Networking I can see the other PC name appear.

My PC is Windows 7 and the other is Windows 8.

I want to see the shared folder(s) on that PC but I cannot.

Why is that? How can I connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on `File and Printer Sharing` on the PC you are trying to connect to:

- Press the windows key
- Type `advanced sharing`
- Press enter
- Select the radio button `Turn on file and printer sharing`
- Press `Save Changes`

If you get a prompt from UAC, click `Continue`